# Is there an annotation or/and import to work with ZeroMQ in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, zeromq

I would like to SUBscribe Data in spring with in my Controller. How can I handle this?

```
@Controller
public class myController {

@RequestMapping("/myGetRequest")
public String myFunction(){

    return **myDataFromZEROMQ**!!?

}
```

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. Please got through the link on how to ask effective questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask